# Laravel polymorphic one to many relationship (A can be linked to B or C)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I am working on a food related Laravel project where I have three main models: RawMaterial, SemiFinished and Finished. A semiFinished object can contain a list of RawMaterial model objects while a Finished object can contain a list of both SemiFinished objects or RawMaterial objects.

I am aware that the solution lies in using polymorphic relationships but I cant seem to get to the right approach.

Please share your ideas on how such a solution would be implemented on both migrations and models/relationships level

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement your own manual polymorphic relationships on your Finished model. Basically how it works is you will need 2 important fields here, which is the `ingredient_id` and `ingredient_type` (change the name to your preference). Then, inside your Finished model, you can make 3 types of relationships, which is `ingredients()` to get all ingredients regarding the type, `semiFinishedIngredients()` to get only the semi finished ingredients, and `rawIngredients()` to get only the raw ingredients. Again, this is optional, add it on your own needs.